# Using the ons-pull-hook without AngularJS

Tags: onsen-ui

I am trying to understand how one would implement the ons-pull-hook component using JQuery. There are no examples available. My code:

```
<ons-pull-hook on-action="load( $done )" var="loader">
    <span ng-switch="loader.getCurrentState()">
        <span ng-switch-when="initial"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-down-a"></ons-icon> Pull down to refresh</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="preaction"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-up-a"></ons-icon> Release to refresh</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="action"><ons-icon size="35px" spin="true" icon="ion-load-d"></ons-icon> Loading ...</span>
    </span>
</ons-pull-hook>

<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">List</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<ons-list id="list" ></ons-list>
```

When I try to reference "loader" in my script it say's that it's not found. Can someone provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

`load( $done )` should be `load( done )`, without '$'. Also, [use `ons.ready`](http://onsen.io/reference/ons.html#method-ready) to get the `loader` variable. Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry but I still can't get it to work. When I try to access "loader" in ons.ready it says it's null. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem here is what I needed to do to get it to work using jQuery.

In my index page I added:

```
<script>
    ons.bootstrap();
    var refreshList;
</script>
```

In my list page I added this to the top:

```
<ons-pull-hook on-action="refreshList( done )" var="myLoader">
    <span ng-switch="myLoader.getCurrentState()">
        <span ng-switch-when="initial"><ons-icon size="15px" icon="fa-long-arrow-down" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Pull down to refresh...</span></span>
        <span ng-switch-when="preaction"><ons-icon size="15px" icon="fa-long-arrow-up" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Release to refresh...</span></span>
        <span ng-switch-when="action"><ons-icon size="18px" spin="true" icon="ion-load-c" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Loading...</span></span>
    </span>
</ons-pull-hook>
```

Then in ons.ready I added:

```
refreshList = function( e ) {            
    setTimeout( function() { getItems( e ); }, 1000 );            
}
```

My function "getItems" needed a callback:

```
function getItems( callback ) {

    // get some items from api and populate list...

    if ( typeof callback !== "undefined" && typeof callback === "function" ) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.